# How to properly implement a user session?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to change the setup of my iPad app. I would like to set it up in a way so that only a certain section requires authentication. Right now, the app verifies authentication on launch, and that is simply not very user friendly, specially when it comes to information that should be visible without having to authenticate.

My question is more along the lines of: How to check for inactivity on the app? So that after 30 minutes or so I automatically log user off.

Has anyone worked on a similar setup that could point me in the right direction?

For what I have gathered, I can use a notification for when the app goes to the background. Should I set up the timer on that method? Will it be preserved when the app is on background? In which case, once that timer reaches the set time, simply log user off? And set up another notification for when the app will enter foreground within that time frame so that it reset's the timer?